# jQuery button click attr('src') returns 'Cannot read property 'on' of null'

Tags: javascript, jquery, src

I'm trying to click on the image and capture the url:

```
  $(".imageitemaddt").on("click", function() {
         imgitem = $(this).attr('src');
         alert(imgitem);
  }); 

  fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
  var $ = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)};

  fabric.Image.fromURL(imgitem, function(img) {
    var oImg = img.set({ left: 50, top: 100, angle: -15 }).scale(0.9);
    canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
    canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);

     img.animate('left', 200, {
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
    });

  });

  $('grayscale').onclick = function() {
    applyFilter(0, this.checked && new f.Grayscale());
  };
  $('invert').onclick = function() {
    applyFilter(1, this.checked && new f.Invert());
  };
  $('remove-white').onclick = function () {
    applyFilter(2, this.checked && new f.RemoveWhite({
      threshold: $('remove-white-threshold').value,
      distance: $('remove-white-distance').value
    }));
  };
```

Returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null

---

**SOLUTION**

add code:

```
    function addtoo(img)
    {
    var nameim = img.src;

}
```

result:

```
function addtoo(img)
{
var nameim = img.src;

  fabric.Image.fromURL(nameim, function(img) {
    var oImg = img.set({ left: 50, top: 100, angle: -15 }).scale(0.9);
    canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
    canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);

     img.animate('left', 200, {
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
    });

  });

  }
```

in the button:

```
<img onclick="addtoo(this)" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wvcsu6ho/6/

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is this? `$('grayscale').onclick`? **1.** Wrong Selector **2.** Calling plain JS methods on jQuery object

Comment: This may happen if you add your images after appending event handlers in `$(".imageitemadd").on("click", function() {...})`. Move it below code that adds images to your page.

Comment: @Tushar that's it http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/

Comment: Why are you defining your own `$()` function as a `getElementById()` shortcut when you are using jquery? Your function will return `null` if no matching element is found.

Comment: You're overriding the jQuery selector anyway, so this should just be a plain old javascript question. as @Tushar said, wrong selector and it isn't jQuery, although you're clearly using it just 19 lines up.

Comment: Are you using jQuery in this page?

Comment: Thank you all. Now Iunderstand that the fabric.js code is not jquery.  I added details in my question

Comment: Solution in my question

Answer (score 2):

Unless you absolutely need to, you shouldn't be overwriting the jQuery **$** selector. What you should be doing is using jQuery in noConflict mode, if using jQuery directly as the selector if you plan on using your own $ selector.

As answered by comment, if the ID doesn't exist, it will always return null.

You're better off using the jQuery selector and updating your code to be:

```
if ($('#grayscale').length > 0) {
    $('#grayscale').on('click', function(e) {
        applyFilter(0, $(this).is(':checked') && new f.Grayscale());
    });
}
```

Comment: That's just an example of what it could be like. You can also use the jquery.on(document) to catch events where the dom is still loading, or is being loaded through ajax.

Comment: understand...message is mostly for OP who copied that `$` over ride directly from link in question

Comment: Thank you very much, I added details in my question. Think better then leaves javascript without jquery

Comment: If this answers your question, please be sure to mark it as the solution.

Comment: Solution in my question

Answer (score 1):

Try using document instead so that it will get the listen to the DOM even if the page is not loaded yet

From:

```
 $(".imageitemadd").on("click", function() {
         imgitem = $(this).attr('src');
         alert(imgitem);
  });
```

To:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".imageitemadd", function() {
         imgitem = $(this).attr('src');
         alert(imgitem);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I added details in my question. I try your example: jsfiddle.net/wvcsu6ho/2

Comment: Solution in my question